# How to derive the thermodynamic activity?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

From wikipedia thermodynamic activity is given as
$$ a = \exp \left(\frac{\mu - \mu_{0}} {RT}\right)$$
which becomes,
$$ RT\ln(a) = \mu - \mu_{0}\tag{1}$$

And i have to do a calculation where activity is given as

$$ RT\ln(a) = \left (\frac{\partial{G_m}}{\partial{N_A}}\right)_{T,P,N_{B}} = G_{M} + (1-c) \left(\frac{\partial{G_{M}}}{\partial{c}}\right)_{T,P,N} \tag{2}  \quad \dagger$$
where
$$G_{M} = RT[c\ln(c) + (1-c)\ln(1-c) + c\ln(1-\beta) - \ln(1-\beta c)] + \frac{\omega c(1-c)} {1-\beta c}$$
$\omega$ is the interchange energy

$$ \omega = ZN(E_{AB}- \frac{E_{AA}+E_{BB}}{2})$$

Z = Coordination number

$E_{AB}$ energy corresponding to bond A-B

$E_{BB}$ energy corresponding to bond B-B

$E_{AA}$ energy corresponding to bond A-A

$\beta$ is the related to the volume ratio of mixing of two liquids.

c is the concentration of liquid A and (1-c) is the concentration of liquid B

$\mu$ is the chemical potential and
$\mu_{0}$ is the standard chemical potential
$N_{A}$ and $N_{B}$ are the number of atoms of A and B

$\dagger$ https://doi.org/10.1080/13642819008208649 (equation 8)

please somebody can elaborate the steps of the (eqn$2$).

Comment: I think it can be simplified a lot if you plug in definitions, already by gathering them inside the logarithm it starts to look like some expression for how many microstates there are (maybe, I'm guessing) $ln(c_A^{c_A}c_B^{c_B}(1-\beta)^{c_A}/(1-\beta c_A))$ but I don't know how $\beta$ is defined. But the expression should be related to how the energy changes if you change the amount of particles.

Comment: Actually I see now that it is not entropy in that term my mistake! It looks rather like a formula for chemical reaction rates in my mind but I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: $\beta$ is defined as 1-va/vb where va is the atomic volume of componet A and vb atomic volume of component B. And yes it is the formula for the chemical reaction of formation of binary liquid alloy.